# Some of the category description not showing up in category page

Tags: categories

I have created the category page using `category.php` template where I have pull the category description. I can see the code is working fine as some of the category description are pulling in the front-end while some of the category description is not showing in category page. I could not find any solution for it.

Here is what I have tried:

1. Updated the category description of the category which is not pulling in category page.
2. I also tried to verify slug conflict by renaming the slug but still its not working.

Below is the code in my category.php file to pull the category description:

```
 <?php if(is_tag()){ ?>
        <p><?php
        $categories = get_the_tags();
        echo $categories[0]->description;
        ?></p>
 <?php } else { ?>
        <p><?php
        $categories = get_the_category();
        echo $categories[0]->description;
        ?></p>
 <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pre-defined function to get a category description.

```
category_description();
```

Visit for more information to [Retrieve category description.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/category_description/)